# ruby on rails - sessions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, session

I'm following this tutorial: http://ruby.railstutorial.org/

I have a problem with my sessions. Every time I login to my application, I get no session but get redirected to my user page.  And create/register users works, too.

**sessions_helper.rb**

```
module SessionsHelper

def sign_in(user)
    cookies.permanent[:remember_token] = user.remember_token
    @current_user = user
    #self.current_user = user
end

def signed_in?
    @current_user != nil
    #!@current_user.nil?
end

def current_user
    @current_user ||= User.find_by_remember_token(cookies[:remember_token])
    #@current_user ||= User.find_by_remember_token(cookies[:remember_token])
end

def current_user?(user)
    @current_user = user
end

def sign_out
    self.current_user = nil
    cookies.delete(:remember_token)
end



def store_location
    session[:return_to] = request.url
end
end
```

**session_controller.rb**

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController

def new
    @title = "| Signin"
end

def create
    user = User.find_by_email(params[:session][:email].downcase)
    if user && user.authenticate(params[:session][:password])
        sign_in user
        redirect_to user
    else
        #Fehlermeldung anzeigen falls login nicht erfolgreich war
        flash.now[:error] = "Invalid email/password combination"
        render 'new'
    end
end

def destroy
    sign_out
    redirect_to root_url
end

end
```

Comment: If i forgot some files, ask me and i'll add these

Comment: well that's what the code does...it signs in the user than redirects to the user page. What are you expecting it to do?

Comment: no. every time i give my account details.. i come to my personal page.. but when i click on the sign in button... it direct me to the sign in page, although i'm already siggned in!

Comment: are you sure you have enabled cookies in your browser?

Comment: yes i have..

@bodrovis sorry but this does not work :/

Comment: Do you want to avoid user seeing login page if the user is logged in? Can't you hide the sign in button if you are logged in?

Answer (score 1):

I see at least one mistake:

```
def current_user?(user)
    @current_user = user
end
```

Should be

```
def current_user?(user)
    @current_user == user
end
```

**==**, not **=**, because you should check that current_user equals some other user, not make an assignment.